# How to create pallet errors that show up on the Polkadot JS apps interface?

Tags: substrate, polkadot-js

So I've been at my wits' end for quite some time regarding `#[pallet::error]` showing up on Polkadot JS apps interface. So as I've come to understand following substrate kitties tutorial that we require to return a `DispatchResult` out of our dispatchable calls and after doing so, I have a case where I am not seeing any errors on my apps interface, although the operation does fail successfully as I don't see any mistakes on the balancesToAccount hashmap.

This code compiles fine.

```rust
#[pallet::call]
    impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        #[pallet::weight(10_000 + T::DbWeight::get().writes(1))]
        /// Allow only Root to mint new tokens & transfer it to some benefactor account
        /// Set a hard uppper limit on the total number of tokens in supply
        pub fn mint(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            #[pallet::compact] amount: <T as Config>::Balance,
            benefactor: T::AccountId,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            // Check if sudo call
            ensure_root(origin.clone())?;

            // Check if existing amount doesn't overflow MaxTokenSupply
Error   |---->  Self::does_adding_overflow_maxtokensupply(amount)?;
            
            // Check if Benefactor already has funds
            let previous_balance = <BalanceToAccount<T>>::try_get(&benefactor).unwrap_or_default();
            let final_balance = previous_balance.saturating_add(amount);
            <BalanceToAccount<T>>::insert(&benefactor, final_balance);
            Self::deposit_event(Event::MintedNewSupply(amount));
            Ok(().into())
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have a helper function that will check if minting `amount` causes a overflow to the total token supply. And that function is defined here:

```rust
impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        fn does_adding_overflow_maxtokensupply(amount: T::Balance) -> Result<(), Error<T>> {
            let total_already_minted: T::Balance = BalanceToAccount::<T>::iter_values().sum();
            let new_supply =
                total_already_minted.checked_add(&amount).ok_or(Error::<T>::MintTypeOverflow)?;
            if new_supply <= T::MaxTokenSupply::get() {
                Ok(())
            } else {
                Err(Error::<T>::MintCausingTotalSupplyOverflow)
            }
        }
    }
```

I was expected `?` to automagically cast the Error into something `DispatchResult` can work with, but I'm not sure if that's happening on this line:

```rust
Self::does_adding_overflow_maxtokensupply(amount)?;
```

Here's what Polkadot JS apps shows when I give it a number greater than max supply :
[image]
Next I check whether that balance went through (It shouldn't), and indeed it didn't go through.
[image: Alice's Balance not updated]

What I would like the apps interface is to show an error rejecting such requests as it does in case of `BadOrigin`. How can I achieve this?

Edit #1: **I should mention that this function is only callable by `sudo`,** if that makes a difference. I can see extrinsic Errors on other functions, except this one.

Comment: Hey, would you be so kind as to repost this great question on https://substrate.stackexchange.com/ -- and @NukeManDan over there?
Very happy to assist on our shiny new Substrate (and friends) home for your questions!

We can cross post the answer here we arrive at there. -- seeing as we have an answer we can just migrate (cleaned up with the commentary to clarify :) )

Comment: I do also see the call to raise an issue, was that done? I agree with @Squirrel

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that this is similar to util.batch - I suspect the sudo is successful whether the internal extrinsic(s) are successful or not and that the UI I suspect is not showing the aggregation of whether all the extrinsics within the wrapper are successful. It is an unsatisfying answer though. I would check to see if this has been raised as an issue in polkadot-js and if not raise it.